# Automated and searchable IT inventory tool

Tags: networking, automation, inventory, digital-asset-management

Is there a product, allowing one, out of the box (!), given a set of login credentials, to collect various properties like hostname, IPs array, roles installed (for Windows), daemons listed (for Linux), kernel version, firmware version (for various network devices), list of network interfaces (for network devices), and so on, of remote systems -- (not dynamic metrics/numbers, for those things there are tools like Munin and Zabbix, although, an all-in-one tool, while too good to be true, is also ok)

I will vote down answers like: write a script that ssh/WMI/telnet/whatever to a set of boxes and grep, bash-it-out, Powershell-it-out and do a lot of other voodoo which would give you the above result, then pipe it to a csv file and later search it with grep. I think the problem is too common for the whole world of IT, for such tool not to exist.

I imagine the tool to be truly useful if it can combine the results (like group specific systems on similarities). Should be able to search for anything. e.g. searching for an IP address would find the system relevant in its' database. Searching for "SQL" would return systems that have "sql" in the hostname, followed by systems that have a package/software (depending on OS) having "SQL" in its name and so on (a hypothetical example).

Comment: What license? And what is your budget?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul , any license and a budget of about $2k pa. I should mention that any especially paid tool should have support for heterogeneous environment. The self-scripted solution becomes much easier when you have only MS products for example, many things can be queries with PS/WMI (and so on). At the same time, nobody expects that 100% of brands and products will be comprehesively supported, but 90% of 90% of common ones should be ;)